# How do I get a display resolution above 1024x768 on my ATI Radeon x800

Tags: xorg, resolution, radeon, xrandr

I've been bashing my head against this for the last few hours on and off. I've a pretty archaic graphics card (radeon X800) connected up to a 37" Samsung Smart TV and I'll be damned if I can get the resolution above 1024x768. I've tried following various guides using xrandr and xorg.config with no success. Even booting into recovery mode to create xorg.config didn't help me as it spat out an error saying the directory didn't exist and dumped out a file called "xorg.config.new" into my home folder. 
Xrandr isn't helping either, I've followed guides to add new modes and always get to this:
**xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default**

I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu, this is my first time on Ubuntu and apart from trying Fedora out a few times it's my first really serious time on Linux so I could be doing something wrong. Any help would be much appreciated, especially by my girlfriend who's getting cranky with me sitting here trying to sort this out.

Comment: If you installed fglrx or one of the related packages, try to uninstall all of them

Answer (score 0):

Exactly which model of X800 do you own?  [This Link](http://www.cnet.com/products/ati-radeon-x800-pro/specs/) states that for the "Pro" variant the maximum resolution is "1600x1200" which falls short of the HDTV's expected 1080p resolution of 1920x1080.  Different models have different maximum resolutions so specifying the exact model you own and also whether it is AGP, PCI, or PCIe will help as well.